# Confused about Polymorphism in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, orm, polymorphism

I am totally lost in polymorphism behavior provided by hibernate. I guess i know the concept of polymorphism i.e. different shapes or form which always exist when there's any inheritance.

Can any of you guys explain me how hibernate has provided polymorphism feature. and how to implement it?

I tried but it gives me the same result in IMPLICIT as well as in EXPLICIT Polymorphism. I don't event know the actual question to ask here. Can you guys give me any hints that takes me any further in polymorphism in hibernate.

Thanks..

Comment: Do you mean inheritance, table strategies, polymorphic queries? There is a bunch of stuff to consider, perhaps this can help you start: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Comment: Can you please define "hibernate" as it is being used above?

Comment: @Kostja: I guess those three topics you mentioned make a way the polymorphism should behave using hibernate. But i am stuck in understanding high level concept about how polymorphism is provided by hibernate.